# How to sort product order?

Tags: ee2

How do you sort product entries in a numeric order in the Categories field of Settings?  I have rearranged the order, saved and the new order does not appear on the site?
Sorry, I am the end user. I have been left to myself for support by BR. They longer offer support of any kind. Just this forum. I am happy to pay for support, but to no avail.

I want to sort the list of products we offer on our website manually....according to our customers use of the products....mattresses, beds, pillows, etc...

The sorting order is defaulting to Pricing in a descending order.

I have tried to manually change the list order by number under Store, Settings, Categories, Products, edit....

A list of all our products appears with a column that has Sort numbers in it. I can change the numbers, save the list and the new order does NOT appear on the website.

Somewhere it is set to order by Price. I want to find that and override it.

Thanks so much,

Jerrie Noyes www.floatingbed.com

Comment: I think your question is a little unclear - can you try rephrasing it? You are trying to order a `channel:entries` tag by what exactly? Or are you trying to set your category order?

Comment: Sorry, I am the end user. I have been left to myself for support by BR. They longer offer support of any kind. Just this forum. I am happy to pay for support, but to no avail. I want to sort the list of products we offer on our website manually....according to our customers use of the products....mattresses, beds, pillows, etc... The sorting order is defaulting to Pricing in a descending order. I have tried to manually change the list order by number under Store, Settings, Categories, Products, edit.... A list of all our products appears with a column that has Sort numbers in it. I can change